# Why does the CUPS OpenWRT admin page prompt for login and will not take user/password when adding printer?

Tags: cups, openwrt

I am using OpenWRT 14.07, with CUPS 1.5.4.  When I try to add a printer, the UI leads me through the entire workflow, until I get to the end.  At the end of the workflow, after I have found the printer, added descriptions, specified drivers, etc.  I click on "Add Printer".

At this point the CUPS admin UI sends me a Basic Auth request asking for a username and pasword in the"CUPS" realm :

> A username and password are being requested by http://192.168.0.1:631.
>   The site says: "CUPS"

I can not get the admin site to accept any username/password combination.   I had seen this before on different screens and entered "root"/"password" and the UI had accepted it there.   I've played around with the setting since then, and now the only time I get prompted for a username and password is when I click on "Add Printer".

I tried to add the printer manually by directly editing the "printers.conf" (against advice and out of desperation).  Now the printer appears, but jobs just disappear. (I assume that the advice was cogent and some queue setup step did not occur) The "manual printer behavior may be a different question, but the applicable observation here is that "Modify Printer" now has the same password behavior.

I am new to CUPS (at this level) and OpenWRT, but I have been using linux for 15-20 years, both personally and professionally in both PC and embedded environments.

Any help is appreciated.  My configurations are attached.  I've been mangling them to try to get around this issue for a while.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
########################################################################
#                                                                      #
# This is the CUPS configuration file.  If you are familiar with       #
# Apache or any of the other popular web servers, we've followed the   #
# same format.  Any configuration variable used here has the same      #
# semantics as the corresponding variable in Apache.  If we need       #
# different functionality then a different name is used to avoid       #
# confusion...                                                         #
#                                                                      #
########################################################################


AccessLog /var/log/cups/access_log
ErrorLog /var/log/cups/error_log
LogLevel debug
PageLog /var/log/cups/page_log
PreserveJobHistory No
PreserveJobFiles No
AutoPurgeJobs Yes
MaxJobs 25
MaxPrinterHistory 10
#Printcap /etc/printcap
#PrintcapFormat BSD
RequestRoot /var/cups
#RemoteRoot remroot
User root 
Group root
SystemGroup root
RIPCache 512k
TempDir /var/cups
Port 631
HostNameLookups Off
KeepAlive On
Browsing On
BrowseProtocols cups
ServerAlias *

<Location />
Order Deny,Allow
Allow From 127.0.0.1
Allow From 192.168.0.0/24
</Location>

<Location /admin>
#AuthType Basic
#AuthClass System
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From 192.168.0.0/24 
</Location>
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/cups/printers.conf
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.5.4
# Written by cupsd on 2015-09-20 16:43
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer Epson_Stylus_NX110>
UUID urn:uuid:957983ba-883f-319a-6eee-20506cef2ea1
Info Epson Stylus NX110
Location Sweet Pea Office
DeviceURI usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1
State Idle
StateTime 1442728667
Type 4
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
<Printer LP>
UUID urn:uuid:9dfe533d-b988-3ed3-4a75-35020e61254c
Info Parallel Port Printer
DeviceURI parallel:/dev/printers/0
State Idle
StateTime 1442718561
Type 4
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
<DefaultPrinter USB>
UUID urn:uuid:781f1f5e-b994-398e-4fd1-198ec9a5f80f
Info USB Printer
DeviceURI usb:/dev/usb/lp0
State Idle
StateTime 1442718561
Type 4
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>D
```

Here is the tail of the error_log, in debug mode

```
[20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 12 POST /admin HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] [CGI] argv[0] = "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] [CGI] envp[0] = "CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] [CGI] envp[1] = "CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:30 +0000] [CGI] envp[2] = "CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/doc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[3] = "CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[4] = "CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[5] = "CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[6] = "CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[7] = "CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[8] = "HOME=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[9] = "PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[10] = "SERVER_ADMIN=root@OpenWrt"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[11] = "SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.4"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[12] = "TMPDIR=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[13] = "USER=root"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[14] = "CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[15] = "CUPS_SERVER=localhost"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[16] = "CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[17] = "IPP_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[18] = "LANG=en_US.UTF8"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[19] = "REDIRECT_STATUS=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[20] = "GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[21] = "SERVER_NAME=192.168.0.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[22] = "SERVER_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[23] = "REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[24] = "REMOTE_HOST=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[25] = "SCRIPT_NAME=/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[26] = "SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/share/doc/cups/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[27] = "SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[28] = "HTTP_COOKIE=org.cups.sid=6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[29] = "HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[30] = "HTTP_REFERER=http://192.168.0.1:631/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[31] = "REQUEST_METHOD=POST"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[32] = "CONTENT_LENGTH=1882"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] envp[33] = "CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------24817083417892195511822523910"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] Started /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi (PID 17554)
I [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi" (pid=17554)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSendCommand: 12 file=14
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] admin.cgi started...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] http=0x77f5aa78
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SECTION="admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REFRESH_PAGE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] org.cups.sid cookie is "6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: org.cups.sid="6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: OP="modify-printer"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: printer_name="Epson_Stylus_NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BAUDRATE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BITS=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PARITY=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: FLOW=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_INFO="Epson Stylus NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_LOCATION="Sweet Pea Office"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_IS_SHARED="on"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_NAME="raw"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: MAX_FILE_SIZE="262144"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_FILE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] op="modify-printer"...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] do_am_printer: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 13 from localhost:631 (IPv6)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 Get-Printer-Attributes 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdIsAuthorized: username=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Returning HTTP Unauthorized for CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 13 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS", trc="y"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] [CGI] cgi_passwd(prompt="Password for nobody on localhost? ") called!
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] PID 17554 (/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi) exited with no errors.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 13
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Script header: Status: 401
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 12 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] Script header: 
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdWriteClient: 12 Closing because Keep-Alive disabled
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 12
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 12 from 192.168.0.2:631 (IPv4)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 12 POST /admin HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: Authorized as root using Basic
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] argv[0] = "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[0] = "CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[1] = "CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[2] = "CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/doc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[3] = "CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[4] = "CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[5] = "CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[6] = "CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[7] = "CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[8] = "HOME=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[9] = "PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[10] = "SERVER_ADMIN=root@OpenWrt"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[11] = "SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.4"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[12] = "TMPDIR=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[13] = "USER=root"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[14] = "CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[15] = "CUPS_SERVER=localhost"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[16] = "CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[17] = "IPP_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[18] = "AUTH_TYPE=Basic"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[19] = "LANG=en_US.UTF8"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[20] = "REDIRECT_STATUS=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[21] = "GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[22] = "SERVER_NAME=192.168.0.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[23] = "SERVER_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[24] = "REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[25] = "REMOTE_HOST=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[26] = "SCRIPT_NAME=/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[27] = "SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/share/doc/cups/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[28] = "REMOTE_USER=root"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[29] = "SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[30] = "HTTP_COOKIE=org.cups.sid=6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[31] = "HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[32] = "HTTP_REFERER=http://192.168.0.1:631/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[33] = "REQUEST_METHOD=POST"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[34] = "CONTENT_LENGTH=1882"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] envp[35] = "CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------24817083417892195511822523910"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] Started /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi (PID 17555)
I [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi" (pid=17555)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSendCommand: 12 file=14
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] admin.cgi started...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] http=0x779c3a78
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SECTION="admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REFRESH_PAGE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] org.cups.sid cookie is "6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: org.cups.sid="6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: OP="modify-printer"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: printer_name="Epson_Stylus_NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BAUDRATE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BITS=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PARITY=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: FLOW=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_INFO="Epson Stylus NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_LOCATION="Sweet Pea Office"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_IS_SHARED="on"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_NAME="raw"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: MAX_FILE_SIZE="262144"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_FILE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] op="modify-printer"...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] do_am_printer: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 13 from localhost:631 (IPv6)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 Get-Printer-Attributes 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdIsAuthorized: username=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Returning HTTP Unauthorized for CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 13 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS", trc="y"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] [CGI] cgi_passwd(prompt="Password for nobody on localhost? ") called!
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] PID 17555 (/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi) exited with no errors.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 13
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Script header: Status: 401
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 12 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] Script header: 
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdWriteClient: 12 Closing because Keep-Alive disabled
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 12
D [20/Sep/2015:16:43:38 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 12 from 192.168.0.2:631 (IPv4)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: clients=1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: jobs=0
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: printers=3
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=564
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=5824
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=11944
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 12 POST /admin HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] argv[0] = "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[0] = "CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[1] = "CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[2] = "CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/doc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[3] = "CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[4] = "CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[5] = "CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[6] = "CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[7] = "CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[8] = "HOME=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[9] = "PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[10] = "SERVER_ADMIN=root@OpenWrt"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[11] = "SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.4"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[12] = "TMPDIR=/var/cups"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[13] = "USER=root"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[14] = "CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[15] = "CUPS_SERVER=localhost"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[16] = "CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[17] = "IPP_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[18] = "LANG=en_US.UTF8"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[19] = "REDIRECT_STATUS=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[20] = "GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[21] = "SERVER_NAME=192.168.0.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[22] = "SERVER_PORT=631"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[23] = "REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[24] = "REMOTE_HOST=192.168.0.2"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[25] = "SCRIPT_NAME=/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[26] = "SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/share/doc/cups/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[27] = "SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[28] = "HTTP_COOKIE=org.cups.sid=6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[29] = "HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[30] = "HTTP_REFERER=http://192.168.0.1:631/admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[31] = "REQUEST_METHOD=POST"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[32] = "CONTENT_LENGTH=1882"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] envp[33] = "CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------15498629441310769008115995165"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] Started /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi (PID 17748)
I [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi" (pid=17748)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdSendCommand: 12 file=14
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] admin.cgi started...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] http=0x77856a78
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SECTION="admin"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REFRESH_PAGE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] org.cups.sid cookie is "6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: org.cups.sid="6f68a69fe0b24073f8995909eb2ae964"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: OP="modify-printer"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: printer_name="Epson_Stylus_NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BAUDRATE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: BITS=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PARITY=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: FLOW=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_INFO="Epson Stylus NX110"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_LOCATION="Sweet Pea Office"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PRINTER_IS_SHARED="on"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_NAME="raw"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: MAX_FILE_SIZE="262144"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: PPD_FILE=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] op="modify-printer"...
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] [CGI] do_am_printer: DEVICE_URI="usb://EPSON/Stylus%20NX110?serial=LJRZ374542&interface=1"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 13 from localhost:631 (IPv6)
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:35 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 Get-Printer-Attributes 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 1.1 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer 1
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdIsAuthorized: username=""
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] Returning HTTP Unauthorized for CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/Epson_Stylus_NX110) from localhost
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 13 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS", trc="y"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] [CGI] cgi_passwd(prompt="Password for nobody on localhost? ") called!
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 13 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 13
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Active clients"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] PID 17748 (/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi) exited with no errors.
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] Script header: Status: 401
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSendHeader: 12 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CUPS"
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] Script header: 
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdWriteClient: 12 Closing because Keep-Alive disabled
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 12
D [20/Sep/2015:16:53:36 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
```

Comment: Have you already set a root password on the device?

Comment: Yes, I can log in as root. Furthermore, CUPS has asked me for and authorized access using the same root password in other places.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create the "lp" user and group, and the "lpadmin" group.
Then I set the User and Group fields in the configuration file to

User=lp
Group=lp

After this, OpenWrt stopped asking me for my password and allowed me to finish the printer setup. I believe that the CUPS 1.5.4 distro has mistaken the permission denied error on cups files as a user authorization failure of the web user,  causing this issue to occur.